# Error writing to server using Google API

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection

```
    URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-us&key=mykey");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "audio/x-flac; rate=16000");
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(bytearray);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream(); //throws io exception
```

so basically I'm trying to send `bytearray` over `httpurlconnection` java.io.IOException: Error writing to server at last line.

Comment: Try to remove `conn.connect();` completely. Does it work now?

Comment: Sadly no, it throws the error again. I added line System.out.print(conn.getResponseMessage()); it returns "Length required". That means i need to specify content-length right? But how do i do it. content length will be size of the bitearray?

Comment: Do you stick on using `HttpURLConnection` natively? If not, there are many libraries doing the heavy lifting for you. Have a look at [DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/#background). BTW do you have the data as bytes already in memory, or is it a File? If file, you could stream the data, so you don't have to keep the whole file in memory.

Comment: good point with the stream but thats not the main problem for now. I dont want to use any libraries if possible.
i did more research if add following method
    `conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);`
server returns    `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error`
and     `Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error`